# TensorFlow on Raspbian Stretch ImportError

Tags: tensorflow, build, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I built `TensorFlow` from source on `Raspbian Stretch`. I encountered a problem though when starting up TensorFlow. I get an ImportError as shown below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "idex.py", line 1, in 
>       import gui
>     File "/home/pi/Desktop/IDEX/scripts/gui.py", line 10, in 
>       import fun_util
>     File "signlang/fun_util.py", line 3, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

I've tried searching for this problem but I couldnt find anything for this particular undefined symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install TF with Keras using pip3 on Raspbian Stretch. It is much faster then building it.
Here what I run following https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/ :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv
pip3 install tensorflow
sudo pip3 install keras
```